# Unexpected Number

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('.price').onclick = function(){function add(3.74)}
```

в конце выдает ошибку Unexpected Number, почему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неправильно:

```
... = function(){function add(3.74)}
                 ^^^^^^^^
```

Потому что `function add(3.74)` выглядит как начало определения (декларации) функции, у которой отсутствует собственно тело функции, но это уже другая ошибка. Параметры в декларации функции должны иметь названия (как переменные), чтобы их можно было использовать внутри кода функции.

Правильно

```
... = function(){add(3.74)}
```